# Distance between title and the plot in radarplot plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want to increase the distance between the title of radar plot with the plot itself but I don't know how to do it.
Reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"

# Create a random data frame with 4 rows and 4 columns
# Column names are M1:M4
# Row names are A, B, C, D
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(
  np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(4, 4)),
  columns=["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"],
  index=list("ABCD")
)

# Create a list of tuples. each tuple shows the position of each
# column in the radar plot. The first element of each tuple is the
# row indicator and the second element is the column indicator.
# Number of radars to be plotted
n_rads = len(df.columns)
positions = [(i//(n_rads//2)+1, i%(n_rads//2)+1) for i in range(n_rads)]

mm_cols = df.apply(lambda x: (min(x), max(x))).values.T

# Create a figure with 2 rows and 2 columns
fig = make_subplots(
  rows=2, cols=2,
  specs=[
    [{"type": "polar"}]*2,
    [{"type": "polar"}]*2
  ],
  subplot_titles=df.columns,
)

# add the traces to the figure
for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns):
  fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatterpolar(
      r=df[col],
      theta=df.index,
      fill='toself',
      name=col
    ),
    row=positions[idx][0],
    col=positions[idx][1]
  )
  fig.update_layout(
    polar=dict(
      radialaxis=dict(
        visible=True,
        range=mm_cols[idx]
      )
    ),
    showlegend=True
  )

fig.show()
```

The following is the snapshot of the first radar and I show what I mean by the *"distance between the title of radar plot with the plot itself"*:
[image]

Note that I'm using `make_subplots`.